# Display Woocommerce variable product dimensions

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce

Have Woocommerce setup with a range of variable products. In the variable tab I've setup a unique price, image, description, weight & dimensions for each item.

All variable data displays as expected on the front-end except the dimensions & weight.

Despite hours of searching, I cannot find any documentation, tutorials, hints on how to hook into it.

Have Woocommerce templates setup and know that I will need to hook into the `do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );` in variable.php.

Anyone know how to get each **variable's dimensions & weight** to display beneath the **variable description**?

Comment: Hi Renegade. Did you ever figure out the way to do this? Seems I have also turned the Internet upside down looking for this info. To no avail... (and doublesharp's answer isn't explicit enough for me to know where to put the suggested code)

Comment: Update: Mostly figure it out now. As per my comment under doublesharp's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the variation ID, you can use it to create a `new WC_Product()`. This object will then have properties available on it for the `$length`, `$width`, and `$height`. See the docs [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) (at the bottom under "Magic Properties").

To get the variations for a given product, you can use the `global $product` and then the `get_available_variations()` function.

```php
global $product
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach ( $variations as $variable_array ){
    $variation = new WC_Product( $variable_array['variation_id'] );
    echo "The length is {$variation->length}.";
}
```

Comment: Thx Doublesharp! I Can see that the variation_id is loaded into `<form ata-product_variations="[{"variation_id":11,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":97 ... etc">` but not sure how to access it

Comment: I update the answer. You get the variations from the parent `global $product`. I think it returns an array of info and then you need to create a new `WC_Product()` to get the proper object, but test to be sure.

Comment: When I select a variation I get the dimensions for all of the variations on screen.

Comment: Thanks Doublesharp. Working with your answer, I was able to product weight to display under the **Additional Information** area (a tab, in my case). I used `echo "Shipping weight of {$variation->sku} is {$variation->weight}<br>";`. I had used sku as the variation identifier because I haven't figure out how to refer to the variation name. Any idea? Also, is there a way I can apply some number formatting to the weight? For instance, to include a leading zero? ie. 0.514 as opposed to .514 .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display additional information regarding your variable product add this function to your child theme’s function.php (or plugin). You’ll probably want to alter the html tags to fit your theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'tim_additional_tab', 9 );

function tim_additional_tab( $product ){

    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    //print the whole array in additional tab and examine it
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($variations);
    //echo '</pre>';
    //html and style to your likings
    foreach ( $variations as $key ){
        echo $key['image']['title'].'<br>';
        echo $key['weight_html'].'<br>';
        echo $key['dimensions_html'].'<br>';
    }

}
```